# How to mirror Xubuntu Laptop to HDMI TV?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, hdmi, display-resolution

The mirror option showing on display is greyed out.

I've used `--same-as xrandr` option to mirror, but that option changes my LSVD (laptop device) resolution mode and HDMI-0(TV) resolution mode to *1280x720*. Then I can't see everything at once on either screen.

Comment: you need to reword your question. It is very hard to tell what you are asking and what you have tried and even what your problem is.  Run `uname  -a` in the terminal to find out what version of lubuntu you have. Post links to the questions/answers you have tried.

Comment: I Apologize, I switched from Lubuntu to xubuntu now i can not change my question tags

Comment: please use [edit] link to edit in your question as well as tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --same-as LVDS
```

this code mirrors screens, but the edges of TV screen needs to be underscanned a bit. I tried with

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set "underscan hborder" # set "underscan vborder" #
```

where `#` is a number. I can not seem to get numbers right and I do not know how to save configuration. Leaving the `--mode 1280x720` out in mirror code eliminates both screens messing up.